# .Net Maui image BaseSize confusion

Tags: c#, image, xaml, maui

The understanding of all the MAui doco I have read indicates -- if you are using an SVG image file in your app

1. The actual size of the SVG file in your project is basically irrelevant
2. You should manually edit the csproj file and be sure to add the BaseSize attribute to the MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\ entry for your SVG file.
3. The BaseSize attribute is is in the format W,H and both the width and height values must be divisible by 8.
4. Additionally, the value for the BaseSize attribute should be the 1 level scale of the image.  My understanding of this is -- the size of the image you would put in a xamarin forms drawable folder or the size of the image you would add to your iOS asset catalog with no @2, @3 in the file name.

So I have done that.  Now I do not understand how Maui is resizing my image.  The settings I have tried are 220,56 and 180,48.  I even tried 64X64.  None of these sizes seem to make any difference in the size of the image.  Between each test, I cleaned the solution and deleted the app from the android emulator.

Using the 220,56 as shown below, I get the as seen in the image below:

```
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\gbsheader.svg" BaseSize="220,56">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </MauiImage>
```

[image]

Using 180,48 as shown below, I get the image below:

```
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\gbsheader.svg" BaseSize="180,48">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </MauiImage>
```

[image]

So then just for kicks I set the base size to 64,64 as show below and got the results below:

```
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\gbsheader.svg" BaseSize="64,64">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </MauiImage>
```

[image]

All three results look exactly the same to me.  Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?  Below is the XAML that contains the definition for image.

```
         x:Class="GBarScene_Maui.PageHeader">
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="imgMenu" Source="hamburgericon.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="btnMenu_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="imgHeader" Source="gbsheader.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO the answer that Liyun Zhang posted did not work for me.  None of the doco I have read states the Resize="true" is required.  Most of what I have read indicates that Resize="true" is the default.  Regardless, in my case - I updated the csproj file as below - First include all the image files, then update them with base size etc.  I found this solution by creating a base Maui project and seeing what the csproj file there looked like for images.  I kept the Resize="true" for good measure.    Not sure why exactly this works and the other way did not work -- but this is working now.

```
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\hamburgericon.svg" BaseSize="64,64" Resize="true">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </MauiImage>
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\cocktail.svg" BaseSize="24,24" Resize="true">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </MauiImage>
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\gbsheader.svg" BaseSize="220,56" Resize="true">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </MauiImage>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its possible that Maui was not updating some internal cache. Maybe the original would have worked, if you quit VS, deleted solution's .bin and .obj folders, tried again. (I agree that it should not be necessary to set Resize="true".) BTW, "220" is not a multiple of 8. Try "224".

Answer (score 0):

You can check the official document about [resizing an image in the .net maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/images#resize-an-image).

**Update：**

I tested again. The `Resize="true"` is not necessary. Just following the maui project template to change the base size and it worked.

```
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
<MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="128,128">
```

I didn't know why I tested it on the android not work without the Resize="true".